# Why @font-face does not work in my web application?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I used @font-face in my Web Application like this :

```
@font-face {

font-family: BKoodak;

src: url('../Content/Styles/ThirdParties/Fonts/BKoodakBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */

src: url('../Content/Styles/ThirdParties/Fonts/BKoodakBold.eot?') format('eot'), /* IE6-IE8 */

url('../Content/Styles/ThirdParties/Fonts/BKoodakBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */

url('../Content/Styles/ThirdParties/Fonts/BKoodakBold.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

}

and then using it like this :

```
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family:BKoodak
  }
```

what is the problem?

EDIT:In network tab(Chrome) i filter font but i find out that the browser don't get the font at all !! and in console i didn't get any 404 error!! i confused! what's wrong?

Comment: Please try to check your console to check if there any error I think it may be path issue . make sure that you don't have 404 errors

Comment: @PeterWilson i checked it before, i dont have 404 error

Comment: what you get when inspect your body element in browser dev tools ?

Comment: @PeterWilson In network tab(Chrom) i filter font but i find out that the browser dont get the font at all !! and mor!! and in console i didnot any 404 error!! i confused! what's wrong?

Comment: I am not talking about the 404 now I am talking about HTML elements try to open your page and right click on any text then choose inspect elements and check the css applied on it I mean how you can see font-family property on it

Comment: @PeterWilson I didnt  see font-family property on it,  so then i added it to a `p` tag, it just effect numeric character! and has not any effect on other character ?!

Comment: Did you tried with another fonts?

Comment: @PeterWilson thank you, i see in another i used font-family before, i remove it and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your file address ?
you could use this code and change file address

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'BKoodakBold';
  src: url('fonts/BKoodakBold.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6–8 */
       url('fonts/BKoodakBold.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
       url('fonts/BKoodakBold.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```